# Solve $z^5=-32$ and draw its solutions in complex space, then describe their characteristic geometrical property.

Tags: geometry, polynomials, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I'm solving past exam questions in preparation for an Applied Mathematics course. I came to the following exercise, which poses some difficulty. *If it's any indication of difficulty, the exercise is only Part 3-A of the sheet, graded for 10%*

> Solve the equation $z^5=-32$ and draw its solutions in complex space, then describe their characteristic geometrical property.

Is it asking to convert z to polar form, then use DeMoivres theorem as I've seen in solutions around the net? If that is the case, how can I work out the $\theta$ angle to be used?

Additionally, what does it refer to as its characteristic geometrical property?

Any answers would be extremely appreciated as they'd help to get me out of the ditch. I'm completely stalled.

Comment: Yes you convert $-32$ into polar form which is $32e^{i\pi}$ (Because -32 is a negative real number so the angle around the argand plane is $\pi$) , You should be able to solve it now using De'Moivres Theorem.

Comment: -2 is a root of this equality, multiplying -2 by the 5th roots of unity other than 1 would give you the 4 other solutions of this equation! And i guess by characteristic properties he means the argument and modulus of each root that is 2 for sure

Comment: @dydxx Wouldn't the angle be 0 instead of π since $tan\theta = \frac{Im}{Re}$ and our z only has a real component?

Comment: @DimitrisS. draw an Argand diagram , a positive real number will have an argument of 0 but a negative will have $\pi$

Comment: If you *know* DeMoivre's theorem this is very, very easy.  The question is really simply asking you if you know DeMoivre's theorem.  $\theta$ is $\pi + 2n\pi$ divided by 5 or $\pi/5 + 2npi/5$ and its "geometric property are the five points of a circle of radius 2 circumscribing a perfect pentagon with one vertex at (-2,0) , or in other words a circle divided into 5 equal parts with on part beginning at (-2,0).

Comment: @DimitrisS. $tan 0$ =  $tan \pi$ = 0 so $\arctan 0 = 0 \implies \pi \text{ or } 0$ are both potential solutions.  However for $z = - 32$ one can simply "see" that $-32 + 0i = |32|*(-1) = 32e^{\pi i}$.  Basically $\theta = 0 \implies$ positive real.  $\theta = \pi \implies $ negative real.

Comment: ... $-\pi/2< \theta < \pi/2 \implies$  positive real.  $\pi/2 < \theta < 3\pi/2 \implies$ r negative real.  $0 <  \theta < \pi \implies$ positive  imaginary.  And $\pi < \theta < 2\pi \implies$ negative imaginary.  So 0 imaginary => 0 or $\pi$ and negative real => between $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$ so $\theta = \pi$.

Comment: "Characteristic geometric property" means "What does it look like?"

Comment: @fleablood your comments on explaining the angle are literal gold, thanks a ton.

Comment: @fleablood one thing however, De Moivre's formula notes $z^n=r^n(cosn\theta +isinn\theta )$ for any complex $z$ of form $z=r(cos\theta +isin\theta )$. How does plugging this in produce any of the 5 roots, I do not understand.

Comment: $z^5 = r^5(\cos 5\theta + i \sin 5\theta) = -32=32(\cos \pi + i \sin \pi)$.  So $r = 2$ and $\theta = \pi/5 + 2k\pi/5 = \pi/5;3\pi/5;\pi;7\pi/5;9\pi/5$. The five roots are $2(\cos \pi/5 + i \sin \pi/5)= 2\cos \pi/5 + i\sin \pi/5;2(\cos 3\pi/5 + i \sin 3\pi/5)= -2\cos 2\pi/5 + i 2\sin 2\pi/5; 2(\cos 5\pi/5 + i \sin 5\pi/5)=-2(-1 + i 0) = -2;2(\cos 7\pi/5 + i 7\sin \pi/5)=2(\cos 3\pi/5 - i\sin 3\pi/5)= -2\cos 2\pi/5-i 2\sin 2\pi/5; 2(\cos 9\pi/5 + i \sin 9\pi/5) = 2\cos \pi/5 - i2 \sin \pi/5$

Comment: Or in other words  $r^5 = 32$ and $5 \theta = \pi + 2k\pi$.

Comment: Here's how I think this problem out.  $z^5 = -32$ well obviously $z = -2$ is one solution.  Now I know the other 4 solutions will be equidistant around a circle of radius 2.  A circle is 360 degrees so the 5 points will be 360/5= 72 degrees apart starting at 180. So ($180 \pm k 72$).  Then I remember that I'm a grown up now and should use radians.  So $\pi \pm k 2\pi/5$ i.e. $\pi/5 + 2k\pi; k = 0,1,2,3,4$.  So the roots are $2e^{i(\pi/5 + 2k\pi/5); k = 0,1,2,3,4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$. Representing $-32$ in the Argand plane you see that, in polar form, it is $-32=32e^{i\pi}$, so your equation becomes:
$$
\left(\rho e^{i\theta}\right)^5=32e^{i\pi}
$$
that gives:
$$
\rho e^{i\theta}=\left( 32e^{i\pi}\right)^{1/5}=2\left(e^{i\pi}\right)^{1/5}
$$
Now, since $e^{i\pi}=e^{i(\pi+2k\pi)}$ we have five distinct values for $\left(e^{i\pi}\right)^{1/5}$:

$$
\left(e^{i(\pi+2k\pi)}\right)^{1/5}=e^{i\pi/5+2ik\pi/5}
$$
for $k=0,1,2,3,4$ and the five complex roots of $-32$ are:
$$
z_1=2e^{i\pi/5} \quad z_2=2e^{3i\pi/5} \quad z_3=2e^{5i\pi/5}=2e^{i\pi}=-2\quad z_4=2e^{7i\pi/5} \quad z_5=2e^{9i\pi/5}
$$

In the Argand plane these points are the vertex of a regular pentagon inscribed in a circle of radius $2$ an with a vertex on $-2$.

Comment: Thank you for the elegant answer. You bypassed DeMoivre's completely, didn't you?

Comment: De Moivre is a consequence of Euler formula, and we can use this last directly.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions should just be $2e^{\frac{2\pi ki}{10}}$, for odd integers $0 \leq k <10$.  They are the divisions of the circle of radius 2 centered at the origin, divided into 5 pieces, rotated about the origin $\frac{2 \pi}{10}$ in the complex plane.

---

Here's more details:

$z^5=-32 \implies 32((\frac{z}{2})^5+1)=0$.  Setting $y=z/2$, and noting that $y^{10}-1=0 \implies (y^5-1)(y^5+1)=0$ indicates that the values of $y$ are the $10$th roots of unity for which $y^5=-1$.  So $y=e^{\frac{2\pi ki}{10}}$ for odd $k$ (even values of $k$ would be roots of the first factor instead).

Comment: I think you mean 0<k<5 ?

Comment: How did you end up at the $2e^{\frac{2\pi ki}{10}}$, dear?

Comment: Now don't you mean 5 pieces?  :)

Comment: Ok I think I've corrected it all.  Sorry, I'm rushing so I made a lot of mistakes.

Comment: I think you mean $2\pi/5$.  You've got 10 on the brain.

Comment: @fleablood No I believe a rotation of $\frac{2 \pi}{5}$ wouldn't change their positions, assuming the first division is at $(1,0)$

Comment: Oh, I guess $\frac{2\pi k}{10};k \text{odd}; 0\le k < 10$ and $\frac{2\pi k}5;0 \le k < 5$ are the same values but...  I wasn't suggesting a rotation,  I as suggesting an expression of the angle.  $2pi/10$ seems a little complicated and misleading as we are dividing 2pi by 5 not 10.

Comment: @fleablood True, but I was rushing for accuracy and validity, not clarity haha.  I'll think about how else I can explain its geometry.